# Apply a calculation to every possible unique subset of a dataframe

Tags: r

I'm facing the following problem: I have a `dataset` with more than `50` rows and approx `100,000` columns, all containing `TRUE/FALSE` values. In this `dataset`,I want to compute the `max colSums` for every possible unique subset of `50,49,48,..,2 rows`, for example I want to compute the maximum column sum of all columns in all subsets of 49 rows .

A brute force approach like the (hasty) one presented below is computationally impossible as for example `(50,30)` produces `4.7129212243e+13` unique combinations, so approaches based on actually finding all subsets  (with combn, combnPrim, powerset or expand.grind) should clearly not be used. How could this problem be solved?

```
dummy<-structure(list(V1 = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), V2 = c(FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), V3 = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), V4 = c(TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), V5 = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), V6 = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), V7 = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), V8 = c(TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), V9 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), V10 = c(TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), V11 = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), V12 = c(FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), V13 = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), V14 = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), V15 = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), V16 = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), V17 = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), V18 = c(TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), V19 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), V20 = c(TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", 
"V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", "V14", "V15", 
"V16", "V17", "V18", "V19", "V20"), row.names = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d"), class = "data.frame")
a<-combn(4,1)
b<-combn(4,2)
c<-combn(4,3)

results<-c()

results[1]<-max(colSums(dummy[b[,1],]),colSums(dummy[b[,2],]),colSums(dummy[b[,3],]),colSums(dummy[b[,4],]),colSums(dummy[b[,5],]),colSums(dummy[b[,6],]))

results[2]<-max(colSums(dummy[c[,1],]),colSums(dummy[c[,2],]),colSums(dummy[c[,3],]),colSums(dummy[c[,4],]))

results[3]<-max(colSums(dummy))
```

Comment: In this example is the correct answer c(1,1,1,1) for the  4 unique rows?

Comment: Then I think your use of the phrase "max column sums" is unclear. It's unclear what is being summed in each case, as well as unclear what sort of uniqueness is being considered. You have 4 rows and they are each "unique".

Comment: Added an example for clearer illustration of the problem, hope that helps.

Comment: Doesn't help. Still unclear why the maximum column sum in each of those distinct rows should be more than 1.

Comment: I think I got the cause of your misunderstanding:  I'm not summing with Boole operators so TRUE+TRUE is not TRUE instead, I'm summing "events" on each column so TRUE +TRUE=2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do `x <- max(colSums(dummy))` (over all rows). For all `n <= nrow(dummy) & n >= x`, there exists a subset of `n` rows where the max of the colSums is also `x` (just choose a subset that keeps all of the rows where the column `which.max(colSums(dummy))` is `TRUE`). For `n < x`, the max of the colSums is `n` (just choose any subset for which all elements of the column `which.max(colSums(dummy))` are `TRUE`).

The solution is `result <- pmin(max(colSums(dummy)), nrow(dummy):2)`.

Comment: Seems very simple after you see it. Thanks for unstucking me :)